# How to add copy code snippet button in React

Tags: reactjs

I have code snippet. I need to add space between different lines so I have `<code>`  and `<pre>` for the code block. I want users to click on a button and copy this entire code as such.

```
import {CopyToClipboard} from 'react-copy-to-clipboard';

let snippet =  <pre><code>  {`
 z <!-- Start of test client code snippet -->

           <script>
               fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
           })(window, document, "script", "_hw", "./widget.js");
           _hw("init", { debug: true, clientID: ${} });

           </script>
 <!-- End of test client code snippet -->
       `}
       </code></pre>


<CopyToClipboard text={snippet}>
          <button>Copy Snippet</button>
          </CopyToClipboard>
```

But it's not working. Does it work only for input field?

Comment: You can copy only string, but your variable `snippet`  type `object`

Comment: @VitaliyRayets any idea how to copy code block like this one? I have to insert clientD dynamically in the string. That's the problem. Hence { }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap all snippet code in literals template.

```
const id = 1;
let snippet = `<pre><code>  
 z <!-- Start of test client code snippet -->

           <script>
               fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
           })(window, document, "script", "_hw", "./widget.js");
           _hw("init", { debug: true, clientID: ${id}});

           </script>
 <!-- End of test client code snippet -->
       
       </code></pre>`;

<CopyToClipboard text={snippet}>
   <button>Copy Snippet</button>
 </CopyToClipboard>
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-work-async-usestate-d7hyg)